# How to check if someone log in continue date using SQL?

Tags: sql

An SQL table called `users` contains data about users. It has columns `firstname`, `lastname`, and `registerdate` (which has type DATE). Write a query that returns the number of users having the first name ‘Sally’ who have registered on each day.

Comment: Show what you've tried so far...

Comment: I am try: select count(lastname) from user where firstname = 'Sally' and registerdate between " " group by lastname; I don't know how to check the registerdate now.

Comment: If you can't answer the question to get the interview,  how well do you think the job is going to go, even if you get hired?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the bit where you do the registerdate between " " your query basically looks fine for the problem description you give, except that you need to group by the date column.

It might be that you need to truncate the date column if it is a datetime value to get the count per date, but if not the query should be:

```
select registerdate, count(*) as "Count of Sally per date"
from "user" 
where firstname = 'Sally' 
group by registerdate
```

Comment: How could you judge the Sally is different person since you didn't consider the lastname?

Comment: @villion I couldn't, but I assumed that the combination firstname/lastname would be unique since you didn't say anything that suggested anything else. Presumably a user can only register once?

Comment: "How could you judge the Sally is different person since you didn't consider the lastname?" **clearly you are just parroting what your lecturer is asking**